# javascript get variable value in <span> in Div

Tags: html, variables

I want to put variable value here, but I don't know the syntax error. How can I use the '' "" .. to put the variable in the below sample ( in  ) ?

```
Leave.innerHTML =  '<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> 
 <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup"> ******Variable Put here****** </span></div>' ;
   }
```

Comment: `'<div>' + yourVariable + '</div>'` or template literal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Exit your string from this point and join the value you want to use and rejoin the initial string.

`'<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">`**'+variable+'**`</span></div>';`

```js
var Leave = document.getElementById("leave");
var variable = "Your variable value goes here";
Leave.innerHTML =  '<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">'+variable+'</span>   </div>';

console.log(Leave.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div id="leave">initial code...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be enough.
`var str = '<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"> <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">' + theVarYouWant + '</span>   </div>'
Leave.innerHTML = str;`